# Jquery Datepicker Rails 3 date format issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

I am trying to use a JQuery UI datepicker for a form for creating an event.

The form itself is rendering fine and if I use the normal rails date_field the information is saved without any issue. However when I try to use the datepicker, it states that the form can't be blank, even if I've picked a date. I realize that this is due to a difference in the format of the dates used by rails and and datepicker, so I've tried the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#dateField").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

But that doesn't seem to have worked. The date is still displaying in the datepickers default format, and is passing that format as a parameter, which results in an error. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few months ago.

Try this format:

```
$(function (){
$('#dateField').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy' });
});
```

It is working fine with all my Rails applicatons.

**EDIT**

Also make sure the datatype of the column where you are saving the date (on the database) is set as `string` and not as `date`.

Comment: I'm afraid that that doesn't seem to work either. The problem is that the datepicker isn't changing the date format no matter what I seem to do so it's still rendering on the page as mm-dd-yy, and passing them as parameter...

Comment: what is the datatype are you using for the column in your database? You should set it as `string` and not `date`

Comment: Though that doesn't really tell me why the datepicker isn't changing it's format.

Comment: that's the problem... rails is expecting something like `2012-07-16 15:51:01 +0100`. Change it to string and you will be able to save any format you want. Sometimes you need to restart the server to see the changes when using jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify what doesn't work? The calendar doesn't appear?
Try this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#dateField").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    });

})
```

And what is default kind of format?

Comment: The default date format for rails is yyyy-mm-dd, whereas with datepicker I believe it mm-dd-yy.

Basically the form returns an error saying that the date can't be blank whenever I try to use date picker, even if I've picked a date

Comment: At the moment the form is also showing that the Jquery UI datepicker still formats the date as mm-dd-yyyy so clearly the dateformat isn't being set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is outdated, with Postgres and a Datetime field I've used
   `{format: "dd/mm/yyyy"}` 
and it did work.